# Тестирование приложения на телефоне

Tags: android, wamp-server

Имеется приложение, которое получает данные из бд. БД и Rest находятся на локальном сервере WampServer.
При попытке авторизации пользователя в приложения, судя по логам, сервер возвращает ошибку 403 (Вроде, доступ запрещен)Как исправить?

Для подключения использую библиотеку Retrofit.

Участок кода:

```
public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.d("Статус",String.valueOf(response.code()));
                        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                            if(!response.body().getError()){
                                finish();
                                SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(response.body().getUser());
                                ///2 строчка
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Авторизация прошла успешно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
                            }
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            if(response.code()==403){
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Сервер не доступен. Пожалуйста, попробуйте позднее",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                toast.show();
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast toast =Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ошибка подключения к серверу. Пожалуйста, попробуйте позднее",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                toast.show();
                            }
                            Log.d("Статус",String.valueOf(response.code()));
                            Log.d("Ошибка",response.errorBody().toString());
                        }
                    }
```

Выкидывает Toast: Сервер не доступен. Пожалуйста, попробуйте позднее.

Моет нужно как-то настроить сервер?

Comment: Для начала надо понять что такое код 403: [ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_кодов_состояния_HTTP#403](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#403) . А затем разбираться почему сервер не даёт доступ к нужному ресурсу или почему Вы обращаетесь к ресурсу, который клиенту не дозволен.

Comment: я знаю, что это за код, доступ запрещен. Но почему он запрещен? Использую SLIM. Проблем с эмулятором не было

Comment: Расшифруйте: _Проблем с эмулятором не было_ . Сам запрос правильный? Чем то ещё проверяли работоспособность? И попробуйте прочесть `errorBody()` - сервер должен давать пояснения к ошибкам.

Comment: Я имел ввиду что приложение работает и получает ответ от локального сервера на эмуляторе

Comment: errorBody().toString - выдает okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@9419305

Comment: `errorBody().string()`

Comment: К сожалению повторить ошибку не могу. Но теперь выдает ошибку при запуске приложения на телефоне:Failed to connect to /192.168.0.100:80. Получается телефон не может к локальному серверу подключиться?

Comment: Вероятно у Вас компьютер получил другой ip - если Вы сами не настроили иное,то ip может меняться хоть при каждом подключении к сети. По основному вопросу - серверу в каком-то конфиге нужно указать сети из которых можно принимать запросы, конкретнее сказать не могу, сам не использовал.

Comment: ip адрес определил командной ipconfig, у меня статический, правда идет инет через локальную сеть(в общаге живу).

Comment: все, я понял как воспроизвести ошибку, раздал с телефона на ноутбук

Comment: Выдало html-код: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
          <html><head>
          <title>403 Forbidden</title>
          </head><body>
          <h1>Forbidden</h1>
          <p>You don't have permission to access /Retrofit/public/login
          on this server.<br />
          </p>
          <hr>
          <address>Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) PHP/5.6.35 Server at 192.168.43.224 Port 80</address>
          </body></html>

Comment: Это Framework Slim

Comment: вы смогли решить вашу задачу?